# How to use TickFunction in python with unreal engine5.1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am using unreal python API to connect python with unreal engine. I am trying to using a [TickFunction](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/PythonAPI/class/TickFunction.html#unreal.TickFunction) function which is basically a Event Tick function appears in agent blueprint.

I want to change the location of an agent 10 times and I want to see this happening in the unreal engine (want to see each time it changes the location).

This is the code I wrote.

```
import unreal

@unreal.uclass()
class Tick(unreal.TickFunction):
    pass

call_tick = Tick()

actorsList = unreal.EditorLevelLibrary.get_all_level_actors()

for i in range(10):
    for actor in actorsList:
        actorLabel = actor.get_actor_label()
        actorPos = actor.get_actor_location()

        if actorLabel == 'agent':
            print('actorLabel= %s actorPos=%s' % (actorLabel, actorPos))

            # initiating tick
            print(call_tick)

            # changing the location
            location = unreal.Vector(actorPos.x, actorPos.y+100, actorPos.z)
            actor.set_actor_location(location, False, True)
```

I am using the tick event function because it may helps to see each location the block will be spotted. the block will change the location after each call of the tick function otherwise it will only show the final location of the block.

Answer (score 0):

This `unreal.TickFunction` is the base class that UE internally uses to define how the tick will behave in actors and components.

Unreal has two main modes: the game mode and the editor mode. Any actor will do that if you want something to tick in the game mode. So you have to create an Actor and overwrite its tick function. If you want to tick in editor mode, you need to change your tick function inside your actor in C++. You can also use an Editor Utility Actor. Here's more information about the topic: https://chriszuko.com/ue4-how-to-editor-tick/

The Python code is currently made to run only in the editor. So if you want to do something 10 times, then you should do it 10 times in your Python code.

Comment: there is no add_actor_component function in actor class

Comment: Yeah - this would only work on the old API, apparently, they also removed the TickComponent. I'll remove the code from the answer

Comment: So @Devanshu, from what I'm looking at, you cannot set the Tick Function through Python. The documentation doesn't give us any way to do it: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/PythonAPI/class/TickFunction.html#unreal-tickfunction

If you want to use Python and you want to use the Tick Function, then I suggest that you try doing is changing the `actor.primary_tick_function` to your instance. But I'm not sure if that will work.

Try extending the actor tick function via blueprint instead in a new actor type. The python API will only work with editor modules, not runtime